# JQuery - tracking window width not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I have been having an issue lately with this piece of code.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  if($(window).width() > 500) {

      $(window).scroll(function() {

      if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("#mainNav").css({background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"})

      } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50){
        $("#mainNav").css({background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + 0.7/50*$(window).scrollTop() + ')'})
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The if($(window).width() > 500) doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why. The if statement always returns false for some reason. FYI: The code inside of the first if statement makes the navigation bar slowly fade into a black.

I thank everyone in advance.

Comment: When you say `The if statement always returns false` what do you mean by that? Your `if($(window).width() > 500)` statement is never running?

Comment: Why isn't it running. By the if statement always returns false I meant that the code inside of it is never runned. I think this is because of the condition returning false. Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: I tried it, and it seems to work. Is your screen width less than 500 when your reload the page?

Comment: Yes it is. The code inside the if statement doesn't run at all. But if i take the if statement out, it all works perfectly but I need the if statement because when my responsive design shrink, I want this code to cancel out.

Comment: your code has a syntax error (maybe fix that). Removing that your code works. See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/v5Lezhwq/

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have the problem fixed for the most part. One last question. Do you know how to check if the user is resizing the page? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah, you can wrap your `if` statement in a `resize` event listener like so: https://jsfiddle.net/v5Lezhwq/1/

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Your method has kinda worked but it's hard to explain how it doesn't so here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/5ncjegbq/5/  Also could you specify what syntax error is in my code. Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: The fiddle almost works until you bring the screen form above 500 to below 500. Then the navigation starts to fade.

Comment: also if the page is refreshed when the screen is above 500 then the navigation just stays fully transparent

Comment: and now it nothing seems to fade at all

Comment: if you think there is a better way to approach this problem then let me know. Also apologies for hanging on a while

Comment: and now both navigations fade.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness I have found a solutuion to the problem now as it is resolved. Thank you once again.